# How to persist chart configurations/modifications in TradingView charting library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, tradingview-api

Hi everyone and happy Friday! Im just here because I have been trying to figure out this and wondering if anyone has any idea or suggestions. I am using the TradingView Library and trying to get the configurations/modifications I made to the chart to be persisted even after a page refresh. For example, if I modify the view of the tradingview library chart, and I refresh the page, the chart erases all modifications and configs I have previously made. Is there any way that I can persist all this data for the current pair that I am on? Not sure where I can accomplish this but below is some code that may be of help:

Comment: hi this probem did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to store data only on frontend, without sending data to backend, there is localstorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
myStorage = window.localStorage;
myStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
const cat = myStorage.getItem('myCat');
```